# Content type changes not reflecting on WSP upgrade

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, solution-package

I have upgraded a WSP in SharePoint Online.

I have added a new column in my content type that I created using module in visual  studio. The new column is not reflecting in my content type associated to a list when i deactivated and activated my feature after WSP solution upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

It will not reflect on already used and existing ContentTypes. You either have to disable and re-enable future to make it work. Or add the fields with the PowerShell script to existing Content Types.

For the new sites where you provision those content types the newly added changes will be there.

Comment: i disabled and enabled the feature, still it did not reflect the changes.

Comment: are you sure the content type is correct and no errors, when activating the future it did not show any errors? Can you create a new list and add a content type? Try this in a new site collection.

Comment: content type is fine and it works in the new list. My new column also reflects in the content type when i see it under site content type. It is the list where in my content type is already associated and on wsp upgrade my associated content type is not updating with that new column in the list.